# Floating Point Numbers

Tags: java

This seems like a real simple question but I just to want clear my doubt. I am looking at code which some other developer wrote. There are some calculations involving floating-point numbers.

Example: `Float fNotAvlbl = new Float(-99);` Why is he creating a new object? What would happen if we do `Float fNotAvlbl = -99;`(-99 is used as flag here to indicate Not Applicable) Later down the code, we define:

```
fltValue1 = 0.00f;
fltValue2 = 0.00f;
```

and populate these two values with a method call which returns float. After that we again convert these two values into Float Objects with:

```
fltVal1 = new Float(fltValue1); 
fltVal2 = new Float(fltValue2);
```

and than do a comparison `if(fltVal1.compareTo(fNotAvailable) == 0) do something.`
Is it all because compareTo expects Wrapper Class Objects?

I apologize if this is a real basic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Writing `Float fNotAvlbl = -99;` relies on autoboxing, which has only been added in Java 5, so older code could not use it.
- Using `-99` as a *Float value* to mean "Not Applicable" is really, really bad. Either use `null` or `Float.Nan`
- `fltVal1.compareTo(fNotAvailable) == 0` means exactly the same as `fltValue1==fltValue2`
- Comparing float values for strict equality should not be done because it will often fail to work as expected. Read [The Float-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/) to understand why.

Comment: just curious, are you sure that the `compareTo` in `Float` doesn't implement some sort of workaround for the floating point equality/comparison issues?

Comment: there are only two differences - `NaN`s and `0.0` vs `-0.0`.

Comment: @justinkt: absolutely sure, from looking at both API doc and source code. It would be incorrect if there were any such "workaround" because it would be wrong for some applications.

Answer (score 2):

- You don't need the wrappers at all
- Even if you needed them, using the constructor is not preferred - use `Float.valueOf(..)` instead.

Comment: Hi Bozho, Thanks for the reply. So whatever he has done is not the best solution? Do you think any reason for him in doing it this way?

Comment: @t0mcat perhaps not knowing how and when to use the wrapper types :)

Comment: @t0mcat - may have been a way to get around floating point equality issues.

Comment: @justkt a futile attempt though.

Comment: @justkt, You can use `Float.compare(float, float)` to compare two floating point values without using an object.

Answer (score 1):

On the subject of what `compareTo()` does compared with `==`

```
float a = Float.NaN;
float b = Float.NaN;
System.out.println(a + " == " + b + " is " + (a == b));
System.out.println(a + ".compareTo(" + b + ") is " + ((Float) a).compareTo(b));

float c = -0.0f;
float d = 0.0f;
System.out.println(c + " == " + d + " is " + (c == d));
System.out.println(c + ".compareTo(" + d + ") is " + ((Float) c).compareTo(d));
```

prints

```
NaN == NaN is false
NaN.compareTo(NaN) is 0
-0.0 == 0.0 is true
-0.0.compareTo(0.0) is -1
```

compareTo compares the binary representation (after normalising all NaN values to be the same) As the binary representation for -0.0f and 0.0f are different compareTo does not return 0. There is no special handling in the code other that to use `floatToIntBits()` and compare that instea dof using `==`

Comment: Thanks Peter, example really helped:)

Answer (score 0):

The comparison may be using the `Float` object rather than the built-in `float` type because of the inherent issues with [floating point comparison](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/Comparing%20floating%20point%20numbers.htm).  Because of the way that floating point numbers are stored on a computer system occasionally the equality comparison between two floating point numbers throws up false negatives.  The `compareTo` from `Float` may take this into account.  The original author possibly at least thought it did.

You can also write your own floating point comparison algorithm that checks for a difference within a reasonable standard deviation for your system.  You can also use the method used by [equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) in Float, which looks at the integer value of the floating point bits for each number.

Note that using Float in and of itself doesn't fix this problem, as the problem is a round-off error in storage.

Comment: Neither Float.compareTo() nor Float.equals() take anything into account other than NaN.

Comment: @Michael - equals does use an int bits comparison, but it doesn't fix storage issues, obviously.

Comment: @justinkt: and that method will return different ints for all differnet floats, except for NaN values.